# Viewport width elements are breaking

Tags: html, css, viewport

I've a problem with some viewport width elements on my website. There are eight divs in a row with a width of 10vw and margin of 2.2222vw. Together the viewport width is about just below 100 (something of 99.9998). The divs are floatet so they should stay in a row.

Everything works just fine but when I'm adding a headline, the elements are breaking. In the fiddle below the divs are breaking without a viewport. Check out my website demo for the "real" issue.

This is my element CSS (SCSS):

```
door {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    border: solid 3px #000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.222vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2.222vw;
    a {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
}

.door.last {
    margin-right: 2.222vw;
    float: right;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z1k80mzt/) | [WEBSITE DEMO](http://headonline.de/ww/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is breaking in your website i dont see it.

Comment: I will add a screenshot :)

Comment: why do you have float right on the last row items?

Comment: This seems like a very fragile way to lay out a grid. I agree with the other comments that `float:right` is causing more harm than good.

Comment: i cant really see the image from workplace its blocked but what i can see is that 1.last row items having float right make them float left as pointed by @Moogs  2.Your parent full-row-alt of floated elements  collapsing fix that.3.you can remove that margin-right from last  row items

Comment: @susanloek take a look into `flexbox` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you, guys! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be your solution, please try this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/bqx5u125/
```

I have added two classes to arrange the divs in horizontal and vertical manner. So this would be the css for those horizontal and veritcal divs.

```
.arrange-horizontally > *{
display: inline-block;}  .arrange-vertically > *{
display: block;}
```

Also, no need of class 'last', and the float:right is the main thing causing you trouble.